# application (search) that supports misspellings

Tags: iphone, sqlite, autocomplete, auto-update

I'm creating a simple application, first time working with SQLite.

1. I want a regular search box and to display results as a user types (is this possible)
2. And how to make the search to be able to support misspellings, if i wrote "Canda" to find me "Canada","Candy" or whatever i have in the DB similar to the search

any help or literature will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning (1), you should take a look at [UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), in short it'll allow you to easily search and display results as you type.

For (2), my first thought would be to perhaps represent the "likely" misspellings in your data model? In addition it would be interesting to also augment this list of misspellings - Apple's own SMS app is doing something like this, so that it learns from your misspellings as you go along.

Comment: Are you suggesting me to make a list of possible misspellings and assign what will they represent?

Comment: Yes, it'd be the way to get things going.  Then, you might allow new misspellings in to the list mapping by using approximate string matching - see links from Claus Broch.

Answer (score 0):

UISearchDisplayController will kick of searches as the user types in text and thus narrowing the results down continously.

To my best of knowledge fuzzy matching is not directly supported in SQLite even though the feature have been requested numerous times.

It requires a quote complex algoritm to do this effectively as detailed in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching).

There exists a module called [fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) for PostgreSQL, but it does have it's limitations, especially with multibyte strings (like UTF-8) which are the native string formats for SQLite. This might give you a hint of a possible implementation.